# Typescript Argument of type never[] is not assignable to parameter of type SetStateAction<never[]>

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a typescript code that assembles the steps of a form and it is giving me an error at build time, this is the function and it's giving me an error on the line:

setVisitedForms((seenForms) => [...seenForms, currentIndex].sort((x, y) => x - y));

```
  const push = useCallback(
    (form = nextForm) => {
      if(!!currentForm) {
        const currentIndex = forms.indexOf(currentForm);
        if (currentIndex >= 0) {
          setVisitedForms((seenForms) => [...seenForms, currentIndex].sort((x, y) => x - y));
        }
        history.push(`${baseurl}${form}`);
      }
    },
    [baseurl, history, nextForm, currentForm, forms, setVisitedForms]
  );
```

**This is the error that appears on the console. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?**

```
Argument of type '(seenForms: never[]) => number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sounds like you don't intend the type of `visitedForms` to be `never[]`, but you wrote:

```
const [visitedForms, setVisitedForms] = useState([])
```

which infers the type `never[]` from the default value `[]`.

Instead, annotate `useState` with the intended type:

```
const [visitedForms, setVisitedForms] = useState<number[]>([])
```

Comment: best answer! Simplest way to rid of the frustration is to initiate an array with `useState<any[]>([])`

Comment: after being stuck for a hour this really helped me. Thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

```
// the problem
const numbers = []
numbers.push(123) // ERROR

// the solution
const numbers = new Array()
numbers.push(123) // OK
```

Comment: This is resolves a problem I have but I don't fully understand why this works

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of SetStateAction.

```
type SetStateAction<S> = S | ((prevState: S) => S);
```

That means that either the argument to setVisitedForms has to be type S or it has to be a function that accepts type S and returns type S.

S is a generic. You can read about them in the typescript docs.

Typescript thinks that seenForms is an empty array: `never[]`, and currentIndex is a number. The setVisitedForms callback has to return the same type as it receives, which in your case is `never[]`, but since currentIndex is a number it returns `number[]`. You need to fix setVisitedForms so that whatever it passes into the callback is type `number[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a type for the `seenForms` argument. In this case `number[]`

```
setVisitedForms((seenForms: number[]) => [...seenForms, currentIndex].sort((x, y) => x - y));
```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately this brought another error - Argument of type '(seenForms: number[]) => number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.